# Using n arguments from Args... starting from position m

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Say I have different functions, which have a variable number of arguments. The first argument is always a pointer obtained through other means. All other arguments I obtain through another template using template pack expansion.
Template that I use for calling these functions is as follows:

```
template<typename RT, typename... Args>
inline RT call(RT(*function)(Args...))
{
    return function(pointer_from_somewhere, bind_argument<Args>::get_arg()...);
}
```

This obviously doesn't compile, as it performs template expansion for all arguments, thus there being too many arguments.
Since I always obtain the first argument through other means, how would I do template pack expansion for `sizeof...(Args) - 1` arguments, starting from the 2nd argument?

**EDIT:**
While the template is slimmed down for demonstration purposes, it might be relevant, that the 1st argument (the pointer) is reinterpret_cast'ed always to the type of first argument. I use `std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type` for finding out the type of the 1st argument.

Comment: Post `bind_argument` as well.

Comment: For demonstration purposes I have slimmed the example to showcase the actual objective/problem. This is for a purpose of an emulator calling a high-level emulated function, for which arguments are passed either from stack or registers (bind_argument does that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
template<typename RT, typename A0, typename... Args>
inline RT call(RT(*function)(A0, Args...))
{
    return function(pointer_from_somewhere, bind_argument<Args>::get_arg()...);
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to add `A0*` to the function parameters?